# Vue 3: v-model and emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model, two-way-binding

I'm trying to use Vue3 two-way biding with `v-model`, but my `emit()` doesn't update the parent value. Could you please tell me where I'm wrong?
Thank you!

Parent looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    
    <LearnersTable
        v-model:toActivate="toActivate"
      />
      <!-- To control if this is being updated -->
      {{ toActivate.length }}


  </div>
</template>



<script setup>
[...]

// List of person to activate
const toActivate = [];

</script>
```

And Children (LearnersTable) looks like:

```
<template>
    [...]

    <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id"  >
        <span>
            <Toggle v-model="row.enabled" @change="onChangeActivate(row)"/>
        </span>
    </tr>
    [...]

</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  
  toActivate: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
});

const emit = defineEmits(['update:toActivate']);

const {
  toActivate,
} = toRefs(props);


function onChangeActivate(row) {

  if (row.enabled === true) {
    toActivate.value.push(row);
  }
  emit('update:toActivate', toActivate.value);
}

</script>
```

I'm omitting a little bit of code here. But the problem is that my emit doesn't work, I don't get the `toActivate` value updated in the parent.

Thank you !

Comment: Try out `to-activate` instead of `toActivate`

Comment: Well, passing from Parent to Child does work, but not back to parent with the emit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make it reactive:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

// List of person to activate
const toActivate = ref([]);

</script>
```

and

```
<LearnersTable
    v-model:to-activate="toActivate"
 />
```